# how to count the total number of competitors on an airport? Need coding help in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am reviewing a dataset on flights and airport details. The dataset contains the following columns with the data about airport and flight details. I am new to coding in R so I need help

| flight_date | op_career | tail_num | flight_num | origin | origin_airport_ID | dest_airport_ID | dest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/13/2019 | AA | N900EV | 3503 | SFO | 11308 | 10397 | LAX |
| 03/13/2019 | AA | N900EZ | 3502 | SFO | 11308 | 10397 | LAX |
| 03/13/2019 | AS | N686BR | 3397 | SFO | 11308 | 10397 | LAX |
| 03/13/2019 | YV | N932LR | 5804 | SFO | 11308 | 10397 | LAX |
| 03/14/2019 | DL | 255NV | 515 | SFO | 11308 | 10397 | LAX |

I want to find the number of competitors on each airport

so in this case a summary output would look something like this

| Airport | competitors |
| --- | --- |
| SFO | 5 |
| LAX | 5 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: the calculation will be based on Op_carrier

Comment: I tried count but it says no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "character"

Answer (score 0):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  select(op_career, origin, dest) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -op_career, names_to = NULL, values_to = 'Airport') %>% 
  dplyr::count(Airport, name = 'competitors')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Airport competitors
  <chr>         <int>
1 LAX               5
2 SFO               5
```

Comment: I tried count but it says no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "character" –

Comment: @newbiedatascientist could be a function masking issue, try with `dplyr::count`

Comment: this is not working. The code does run but its not producing the right results. Can you show me how to do this for summary df?

Comment: @newbiedatascientist your expected in the post shows 5, 5, which I think I am getting with my code?

Comment: do you know how to do it without the pivot? I want to create a summary datafile which shows the route and the number of competitors on it. I have already created the column for routes. I just need to find how many competitors are operating on these airports.

Comment: @newbiedatascientist is this a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73733557/how-to-find-the-busiest-airports-from-a-dataset-in-r/73733585#73733585)

Comment: yes it is . I just need a summary file